# Switch branch without committing the working code

Tags: git

I'm using `git` for source code repository and the current code in a messy state and want to switch to other branches for a bit of work. The issue is that I don't want to do a commit of half-done work just, so how can I get back to this point later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two option to do this.

Option 1: - Create the patch for the working code and checkout that all the working code then switches into the another branch.

Option 2:- You can stash your branches. Click here  for more detail example: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash

Comment: Link seems dead to me. Another interesting link about stashing : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-stash

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to "discard" changes for a while and then, when you want to restore your previous changes use `git stash pop`*

You can also (and is safer) commit your WIP (Work In Progress) work, switch to another branch, do your work, switch back to original branch, finish original work and then [squash](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) your commits into just one.
Remember that commit isn't equal to pushing, so you can locally have a messy history but, once rebased and squashed, you (and your team) will only see the clean version.

*pay attention because if you stash more than one time, git pop will pop only last stash. In this case you need to use `git pop stash@{<revision>}`

Answer (score 3):

If you have the newer git (>=ver.2.5.0), you can use *git worktree*.

By the following command, you can checkout a temporary worktree to use.

> git worktree add sourcetree_dir branch_name

After finished your work on this branch , you can use the following command to delete it.

> git worktree prune

Answer (score 2):

Using the command line, short answer:

```
git stash
git checkout otherBranch
```

If the brach is in origin use:

```
git checkout origin otherBranch

..
do your changes/commits
..
git stash apply
```

With `git stash apply` you get back your previous changes. You could find merge conflicts...fixed them and commit again.

Answer (score 1):

You can stash your branches. Here is an example:
http://www.gitguys.com/topics/temporarily-stashing-your-work/

Comment: Please provide some code. Links should be only addition to answer

Comment: Link seems dead to me. Another interesting link about stashing : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-stash

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create another directory and clone the desired branch into it?

If you have a runtime configured to use particular directory, make it a link to the branch clone directory you are currently working with. This way you could have more than one branch locally without much reshuffling of your local resources (just a plain script to re-link directory used by your runtime/server).